# Sidekiq crashes every few hours in docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, logging, redis, sidekiq

I am facing an issue in which sidekiq crashes every few hours in docker. Investigating the logs reveals a "TimeoutError" when sidekiq tries to connect to redis and restarting the containers does not work. The only way I can get the get it to work again is by restarting the docker daemon.

After lots of investigation, I believe the root cause has to do with logging problems in docker not keeping up with redis logs. The diagnosis I saw for this comes from [this post](https://meta.discourse.org/t/discourse-web-interface-becomes-unresponsive-a-few-minutes-after-starting/76643/11). Their solution was to [downgrade docker](https://meta.discourse.org/t/discourse-web-interface-becomes-unresponsive-a-few-minutes-after-starting/76643/14), but it seems docker is still not fixed up to version 19.03.3, so the solution of reverting to an old docker version is not feasible.

Any possible workaround other than downgrading is possible? Did anyone face this issue before? Any suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am crossing my fingers but I *think* I have a workaround.

Since the problem seems to be hovering around logging issues. The straightforward solutions seems to either disable logging or set logging mode to "non-blocking" for the redis container to which sidekiq is trying to connect.

I provide below a sample docker-compose file to explain how to do this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  ruby:
    build: .
    command: rails s
  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
  db:
    image: "postgres:11.1"
  redis:
    image: "redis:4.0"
    logging:
      mode: non-blocking
      # or
      # driver: none
```

It's been about 8 hours so far. If this continues to run smoothly until tomorrow, then perhaps it's a reasonable workaround for now.